# Use PDF output of one l3build test in next test?

Tags: l3build

Is it possible to use the PDF output of a `l3build` test as an included file in a following test?

e.g.,

**`test000.lvt`:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{regression-test}
\START
\showoutput
\begin{document}
Filler text.
\end{document}
\END
```

Can I somehow set things up so I can include the output of this in the next test?

**`test001.lvt`:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{regression-test}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\START
\showoutput
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test000}
\end{document}
\END
```

I can produce `test000.pdf` and `test000.tlg` by running `l3build save test000`, but then running `l3build save test001` appears to delete all the build files from `test000`. So I am not even able to produce `test001.tlg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: 'no'.

The output of *tests* can't be relied on to be present by other tests. Indeed, one can run a single test in isolation and it should give the same results. What you seem to want here is a 'support' file for a test, which is a *fixed* piece of input used in addition to a test file itself. That is commonly the case for *e.g.* `.bbl` files but can also a a PDF. See `checksuppfiles`.

Comment: You are exactly right. I do want a PDF support file for the tests. I could of course build this by hand and upload it to the testfiles support directory (I have in fact done this). I just wondered if there was a way to only include the LaTeX source for this PDF in GitHub, rather than both the source and PDF output. Pretty minor wish, I know... Perhaps I'm wanting `l3build` to be as flexible as Makefiles and it's not designed to be so general.

Comment: @DavidPurton The problem here is that however you run it, using the output of one test for a second means you are fixing the order: how do you run _just_ the second test (say if you are tracking down a problem)?